# What is the fastest route by vehicle from Victoria to Tofino?

Tags: tofino, victoria-bc

The commonest route is the Pacific Coast Highway via Nanaimo (ie: [C](https://www.google.ca/maps/dir/Tofino,+BC/Victoria,+BC/@48.8733222,-125.7567466,8z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x548990ccb0093843:0x331095695a741a35!2m2!1d-125.9066184!2d49.1529842!1m5!1m1!1s0x548f738bddb06171:0x38e8f3741ebb48ed!2m2!1d-123.3656444!2d48.4284207?hl=en) below), as suggested by [Tourism Tofino](http://www.tourismtofino.com/getting-to-tofino/road). But is it really the fastest by vehicle?

Is not there some faster route through the Cowichan Bay and the forests (something faster than [I](https://www.google.ca/maps/dir/Tofino,+BC/Victoria,+BC/@48.8733222,-125.7567466,8z/data=!4m19!4m18!1m10!1m1!1s0x548990ccb0093843:0x331095695a741a35!2m2!1d-125.9066184!2d49.1529842!3m4!1m2!1d-124.4699064!2d48.9230836!3s0x5488dae3a40cbb7f:0x834eb5a3a4de20ac!1m5!1m1!1s0x548f738bddb06171:0x38e8f3741ebb48ed!2m2!1d-123.3656444!2d48.4284207!3e0?hl=en) below at 335 km > C at 315 km)?

My aunt fears small airplanes and airlines, and so refuses to [fly into Tofino](http://www.tourismtofino.com/getting-to-tofino/air).

[image]

Comment: Google maps has already given you the fastest route. What makes you believe that there would be an even faster way?

Comment: @GregHewgill I fear that  Google Maps may be wrong?

Comment: Google being wrong doesn't happen very often. And it is possible to [overcome a fear of flying](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/22736/3221).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Google Maps is not wrong in this case. Highways 1 and 19 (Victoria to Qualicum Beach) are high quality four lane roads with a speed limit of around 100 km/h (there may be faster or slower bits).

On the other hand, the back roads behind Cowichan Lake through to Port Alberni are narrow, winding gravel roads where you will struggle to make an average of 50 km/h safely.

Victoria to Tofino will take at least four hours (that's optimistic). It is not possible to arrive sooner by driving a different route.